# Cant see the bundle folder on iOS 8

Tags: file-transfer, ios

I'm a developer and usually I need to see my app folders with programs like iExplorer or iPad File Explorer and I installed the released to the public version of iOS 8 into a device and now I can't see the bundle folder of any app, only Library, Documents and tmp.

How do I read files from iOS devices over USB from a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot I posted this question. The answer is iOS 8 now stores the bundle on a separated folder. Programs are still no able to read it.